# LIBSVM - can grid.py be used with a linear kernel?

Tags: svm, libsvm

`LIBSVM` has a python function `grid.py` that, to my understanding, applies parameter selection using a method called `grid-search`.

The `README` file specifically states that:

```
grid.py is a parameter selection tool for C-SVM classification using the RBF
(radial basis function) kernel.
```

So it's supposed to be for **RBF**.

In order to run the file:

```
Usage: grid.py [grid_options] [svm_options] dataset
```

But if I use`-t 0` (for a linear classifier instead of RBF) as an `svm-option` - will it classify linearly?

I apologize about the weird question; I think it's odd that all the documentaries of LIBSVM keep emphasizing that `grid.py` is *only* for RBF if it could be changed with the `options`...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems like one can use grid.py for other than RBF kernel (i.e. linear kernel).

Linear kernel with parameter selection
python grid.py -log2c -1,2,1 -log2g 1,1,1 -t 0 leu.combined

(taken from the guide: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf)
(Faced the same problem too, hehe)